# IndexPath wrong after array sorting

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, sorting, indexpath

i get an weird behavior. 
Every time I sort my array, my tableView not conforms to my new sorting.

The arrangement is changed but when I select a row the indexpath is not correct.

```
func SortShoppingListItemsArrayBy_isSelected() -> Void {
    if ShoppingListsArray[currentShoppingListIndex].ItemsArray!.count > 0{
        ShoppingListsArray[currentShoppingListIndex].ItemsArray!.sort{ !$0.isSelected! && $1.isSelected! }
        ShoppingListDetailTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Does anybody can tell me why?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if ShoppingListsArray[currentShoppingListIndex].ItemsArray!.count > 0 {
        let row = indexPath.row
        //Allow only select on checked items => unchecked must be dropped to basket
        if ShoppingListsArray[currentShoppingListIndex].ItemsArray![row].isSelected == false { return }
        ShoppingListsArray[currentShoppingListIndex].ItemsArray![row].isSelected  = ShoppingListsArray[currentShoppingListIndex].ItemsArray![row].isSelected == false ? true : false
        firebaseShoppingListItem.EditIsSelectedOnShoppingListItem(list: ShoppingListsArray[currentShoppingListIndex], shoppingListItem: ShoppingListsArray[currentShoppingListIndex].ItemsArray![row])
    }
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String.ShoppingListItemTableViewCell_Identifier, for: indexPath) as! ShoppingListItemTableViewCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.ConfigureCell(shoppingListItem: ShoppingListsArray[currentShoppingListIndex].ItemsArray![indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You should never check if count > 0. You should check if `yourArray.isEmpty`

Comment: Don't force unwrap your array. Use guard to unwrap your optional

Comment: It is Swift convention to name your variables starting with a lowercase letter

Comment: It's probably a *value type semantics* issue. Not related but why is `ItemsArray` – a part of the data source – and `isSelected` optional?

Comment: @LeoDabus, can you elaborate on the use of count (never use) vs isEmpty(should always use).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array Use the isEmpty property to check quickly whether an array has any elements, or use the count property to find the number of elements in the array.

Comment: Can you explain why you think the IndexPath is wrong. Please explain what you expect it to do and what it is actually doing.

Comment: In my case after sorting my items are sorted by isSelected. And when I try to deselect, an item at other position gets deselected and not the touched one.

Comment: After sorting my array. The indexpath does not conform to the current index of my array. It is weird. I select a row on the tableview but it does not conform to the selected position inside the array.

For example I select item 4 on my tableview, but item two reacts to the **didSelectCellForRowAtIndexPath** delegate. So the array index and the indexpath seem to be messed up and not synced. @vadian  my structure is buld like that: Array of ShoppingLists with a subarray of items. Its optional because in my class of ShoppingList the subarray Items is optional. Not needed but atm it is this way

Comment: At least i got it running. Not sure what caused the problem. I changed my database structure that lead to different kind of data.